# KMM no Android Studio build returna Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: mobile, kotlin, gradle, cross-platform

Recentemente criei um novo projeto KMM via KMM plugin, mas não consigo rodar ou mesmo fazer debug na parte  Xcode iosApp do projeto. Quando eu tento executar o iosApp pelo Android Studio, o processo de build falha (Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with nonzero exit code)

As linhas finais do build foram:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':shared:compileKotlinIosX64'.

Compilation finished with errors

Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 8s 1 actionable task: 1 executed Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed: PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/tamegajr/AndroidStudioProjects/TesteKMM5/build/ios/iosApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-7555FFB5242A651A00829871.sh (1 failure)

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -3):

Após rever alguns códigos de 2-3 mês atrás de projetos exemplos de KMM e compará-los com novos, eu descobri a solução para a falha de build quando tentava executar iosApp nos Simuladores Ios, apenas faça a esta alteração ao build.gradle.kts na raíz do projeto:

A partir do plugin KMM você terá (nas dependencies):

classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10")

Mude para:

classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31")

E é isso, problema resolvido. Eu espero que alguém na Jetbrains possa resolver esse problema em autalizações futuras do plugin KMM.